# Problem understanding a part of a contract. Help please~

Tags: expressions

Could anyone write the below sentence in a simpler, easier to understand version in English? Thank you in advance!

Notwithstanding the foregoing, Consultant agrees that Consultant shall not bundle with or incorporate into any deliveries provided to the Company herewith any third party products, ideas, processes, or other techniques, without the express, written prior approval of the Company.

Comment: If you individually search the terms, you'd find that you can grasp the meaning quite easily. It means that despite whatever was mentioned before, the consultant should not put or add anything to the deliveries meant for the company mentioned in the letter without first getting approval from the company.

Comment: @tchrist - I am not supposed to rewrite this for anyone. I just need to understand what it means, and that is why I asked ppl here to give me a simpler version ( for me to understand). The whole thing is one sentence, and because of the structure and some expressions, like 'bundle with' and 'incorporate into',  I couldn't understand it. Rather than asking each and every word and expressions, I thought asking for a simpler version would save everyone's time.

Comment: @vickyace and jlovegren, Thank you both for helping. I had no clue even with my dictionary, but your sentences are much clear. (The words in contracts are unnecessarily hard for non-native English speakers like me :(  ) Thank you, again!

Comment: The words in contracts are *necessarily* hard for non-attorneys, native speakers of English or no. That's because they're written in legal language, something that requires specialized training to understand. It's a bad idea to ask random strangers in cyberspace to interpret legalese for you. People here don't even know what law governs your jurisdiction, not to mention that they don't know the context of your post. What's in the "foregoing", for instance. If you don't understand what you're being asked to sign, spend a little money to have an attorney explain it to you.

Comment: @deadrat, Thanks for the comment. I'd definitely pay someone to translate it for me if I was going to sign it. I'm just studying English legalese by reading different pieces of contracts.

Comment: Just to add--there's a difference between understanding the sentence in a contract, and understanding its implications. Local laws will govern how the *court* interprets this sentence, which may bear very little resemblance to the words written on the page. It's likely they're protecting themselves against copyright/patent infringement by saying that you were not implicitly authorized to use works created by someone else. That leaves you responsible if someone files a suit against them. You should ask an attorney to explain the meaning.

Comment: You can also check out [law.se] Stack Exchange for Legalese and stuff like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of the legal language:

> Despite the previously mentioned fact, the Consultant agrees that he/she will not include any additional third party products, ideas, processes, or other techniques in any deliveries that the Consultant provides to the Company without the explicit, written, and prior approval of the Company.

(Basically, the Consultant agrees to only deliver what was agreed upon in the contract and to not bundle any third-party stuff in those deliveries without the Company's explicit approval)

Comment: Thank you, AleksandrH. So, "do what's been agreed and do not mix anything else from outside without their approval," right? Thank you so much : D

Comment: The last paragraph is incorrect.  Extra stuff is not the issue.  The problem is stuff from third parties.  It's a precaution against the company's being made a party to the consultant's potential violation of some other party's intellectual property rights.  Otherwise, it's a good answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, Thank you for additional comment. I have lots of notes and corrections on my study paper today. Thanks to you all :)

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks, I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 0):

This is boilerplate used to shield the company hiring a contractor from any lawsuits for patent infringement, disclosure of trade secrets, etc. If the infringement is in any way related to the contractor, they use this clause to shift the blame onto the contractor. That's reasonable if a bona fide contractor works with several companies in the same sector, and they need to be expected to treat confidential information appropriately.

The "notwithstanding" is meant to clarify that the previous sentence shouldn't be construed to let the contractor incorporate third party (i.e., not their own) ideas, etc. The previous sentence probably talks about scenarios involving the consultant's work with third parties.

You also start to see de facto full time employees signing contracts as sham contractors, because the company would like to (a) prevent employees from having standard labor protections that they are normally entitled to; and (b) they don't want to pay FICA tax or offer employees health insurance.

Notwithstanding the foregoing, no legal advice is herein offered.

Comment: jlovegren, thank you so much for detailed explanation on my question. What a great example sentence at the end! ;) The word 'notwithstanding' was one of the words that made me go "huh?" The previous sentence talks about the consultant's right to disclose the information and skills he/she gained while working with 3rd parties, which is exactly what you said. Thank you again for not just passing by and giving me the detailed explanation!